# Magento category controller full page cache issue

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, full-page-cache

I'm using 3rd party fpc extension. When i enable fpc observer calling only once, next time & onwards the observer code not executing. When i exclude entire category controller, view action from fpc is working fine.
Can you help me on this issue?

**event xml:**

```
<catalog_controller_category_init_after>
    <observers>
        <sfm>
            <class>Dcw_Sfm_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>ymmsCheck</method>
        </sfm>
    </observers>
</catalog_controller_category_init_after>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php      
class Dcw_Sfm_Model_Observer 
{
    public function ymmsCheck(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $sfm='';
        if (isset($_COOKIE["sfm"]))
            $sfm = $_COOKIE["sfm"];
            $sfmx = '';
        if (isset($_COOKIE["sfmx"]))
            $sfmx = $_COOKIE["sfmx"];

        if ($sfm != '' && $sfmx != '') {
            $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
            if (strpos($currentUrl, 'sfm') == false) {
                if ($sfm == 1) {
                    $type = "style";
                } else if ($sfm == 2) {
                    $type = "family";
                } else if ($sfm == 3) {
                    $type = "model";
                }
                $currentNewUrl = $currentUrl . "?sfm=" . $sfm . "&" . $type . "=" . $sfmx;
                $response = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse();
                $response->setRedirect($currentNewUrl);
                $response->sendResponse();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
?>
```